# Metro app (windows 8, winrt). Can I add new in-app purchase products after my application will available on Windows Store without updating application

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, in-app-purchase, windows-runtime, windows-store

I develop metro (windows 8, winrt) application for selling ebooks. I want to use **Windows store** as the payment processor to support Windows Store **in-app purchases**.

I am interested in next questions:

1. Can I add new in-app purchase products after my application will available on Windows Store without updating application? 
   (Or I will always need to update app when create a new in-app purchase product ?)
2. Can I add new in-app purchase product programmatically (dynamically) to Windows Store in-app purchase products list?
3. If I will add 100 new books every day - I will need every day add 100 new in-app purchase products?
4. Is there limitation to count of in-app purchase products?

Answer (score 2):

You can always add new in-app purchases after your app is approved in the Windows Store; however, for your scenario it sounds like you might be better off rolling your own third-party payment system and using that instead.

That way you aren't bottlenecked by the Windows Store and don't lose a 30% cut (eventually 20% if your app exceeds $20k in lifetime sales, which includes in app purchases.) The trade off is that you have to convince users to provide you with some other form of payment information (PayPal, recurring billing on a credit card, etc...)

If you can tolerate the turn-around time of the Windows Store, that option would probably be easiest for you.

Comment: Is providing an external link to a payment system allowed by the windows 8 in-app purchase policies, as in these cases MS dont get their share (30%)??

Comment: Yes, it's allowed - Microsoft's TOS more or less says "if you want to use our payment engine and not have to handle PCI and ask for credit cards, we take a cut. If you want to do your own thing, we don't take a cut."

Answer (score 0):

You should always update you app, but:

- If you update only products - your app will be reviewed faster than
  usualy.
- Also, you can list some extra products. To have a some kind of
  buffer.

I suggest you to ask your question [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsstore/threads/)